# Create associative array php similar to Hashmap in java were key is string and value is list of string

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a mysql resultset as below

```
-------------------------------------
     name     |     sector
-------------------------------------
     walmart        retail
     subway         restaurant
     papaya         retail
     dennys         restaurant
```

I want a php array as below

( "retail" -> "walmart, papaya" , "restaurant" -> "subway, dennys")

What is the bestway to create an associative array as above.

All I have till now is this.

```
$query = "SELECT bd.businessname, bd.businesssector
                      FROM businessdetail bd , businessoffer bo
                      WHERE bd.id = bo.businessid and bd.isactive=1 and bo.isactive=1
                      GROUP BY bd.businessname, bd.businesssector";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$resultset = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
   // create associative array    
}
```

Comment: By first extracting the data from the database. Have you made an attempt at that? If so, please showcase what you have so far.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$result->fetch_assoc()` instead of `$result->fetch_row()`, then in the while loop:

```
$resultset[$row['businesssector']][] = $row['businessname'];
```

After you are done iterating you'd have an associative array where the key is your business sector and the value is another array containing names of the businesses. Later you can use `implode()` to create a string with all the names delimited by a character of your choice OR in the while loop you can actually append to a string instead of pushing elements to the array.

Comment: No need at all for the `if` statement.